# detect checkbox state change

Tags: jquery

I want to detect if user checks or unchecks a check box within an iframe and set a flag like so. But it does not seem to work as expected. Any pointers on the error on the code?

```
jQuery("#frameName").contents().find(":checkbox").bind('change', function(){        
            val = true;
            alert("changed");
    });
```

But I can detect if a checkbox is checked by using

```
var val = jQuery("#frameName").contents().find(":checkbox").is(":checked");
```

I want to be able to detect any state change on a checkbox and set the flag.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `checked` DOM property to check whether a checkbox is checked or not. The `change` event is always triggered on change, even if the checkbox gets unchecked.

```
jQuery("#frameName").contents().find(":checkbox").bind('change', function(){        
        val = this.checked; //<---
        alert("changed");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not detect the state change at all.

Answer (score 3):

Bind to the click event, not change. Checkboxes work on click.

EDIT: It appears in modern browsers that changing the state of a checkbox, whether via mouse or keyboard, triggers at least the `click` *and* the `change` events.

See a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/tgHtN/) I built for proof. Using the keyboard also triggers some key-related events, in addition to `click` and `change`.

Comment: Unless your user is using their keyboard.

Comment: @sscirrus Actually, we were both wrong initially - using IE10, Firefox 20.0.1, and Chrome 26.0.1410.64, all browsers triggered the change and click events. See my edit for a link to a demo.

Comment: it may work in the latest browsers but the OP's users are likely to suffer greater backwards compatibility and/or accessibility issues by using `click`. Whereas `click` is a method of generating a `change`, `change` is ultimately the event we are looking for.

Comment: Agree with @sscirrus. When you bind to the `change` event, you can programmatically check/uncheck and they'll be detected.

Comment: @GregL How does one detect a "programmatic change" in the checkbox state?

Comment: @WorkWise By "programmatic change" I mean one where code is run to change the value of the checkbox's `checked` state, and then the `change` event is manually triggered (possibly using `jQuery(...).trigger('change')`. You can see one way of detecting if this was what caused the `change` event handler to be fired by seeing [this forked jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/5dj3302h/).