# How to detect the change of checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many check boxes and radio buttons on my form. If I have checked any checkbox and click on save, I get a message "you have updated your profile". However if I dont check any checkbox and click on save, I should get a message "You have NOT updated your profile". for eg, AGain... I should get a message "You did NOT updated your profile"

1. Checkbox1 is unchecked. I checked it and unchecked it again.
2. checkbox2 is checked. I uncheck it, and checked it again.

If I click on save in above two scenarios, I should get "NOT updated profile" message as the values are still same as before. Help me how to do this.

Comment: if possible share your HTML please?

Comment: Just before launch your update SQL statement, compare all the values that must be updated, if all the values are equals, change the message ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect checkbox state change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919716/detect-checkbox-state-change)

Answer (score 3):

In your handler on the save button, you can compare the current value of the checkboxes with their *original* value from the HTML markup:

```
var cbchanged = false;
$("selector matching the checkboxes").each(function() {
    if (this.defaultChecked !== this.checked) {
        cbchanged = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

The `defaultChecked` property is `true` or `false` depending on whether the checkbox was *originally* checked. The `checked` property is `true` or `false` depending on whether it's *currently* checked.

Complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ijefos/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ijefos/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Checkbox Default State</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div><label><input type="checkbox" checked>First</label></div>
  <div><label><input type="checkbox">Second</label></div>
  <div><label><input type="checkbox" checked>Third</label></div>
  <div><input id="saveButton" type="button" value="Save"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      $("#saveButton").click(function() {
        var cbchanged = false;
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
            if (this.defaultChecked !== this.checked) {
                cbchanged = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        alert(cbchanged
              ? "You HAVE changed something"
              : "You have NOT changed something");
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript version checking the div.(alot faster than jQuery)

sets the default var in the def variable.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 var d=document,
 changed=false,
 change=function(){
  var c=0,l=cb.length;
  while(l--){if(cb[l].checked!==def[l]){c++}};
  changed=c>0;
 },
 check=function(){
  alert(changed?'something changed':'nothing changed');
  changed=false;
 },
 cb=d.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'),
 l=cb.length,
 def=[];
 while(l--){def[l]=cb[l].checked};
 d.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener('change',change,false);
 d.getElementById('saveButton').addEventListener('click',check,false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked>First</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Second</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked>Third</label>
<input id="saveButton" type="button" value="Save">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this version just checks for changes even if you change back it's a change.
no loops,no multiple checks, no jQuery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
var changed=false,
h=function(){
 changed=true;
},
check=function(){
 alert(changed?'something changed':'nothing changed');
 changed=false;
};
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].addEventListener('change',h,false);
document.getElementById('saveButton').addEventListener('click',check,false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked>First</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Second</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked>Third</label>
<input id="saveButton" type="button" value="Save">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```