# How to detect a checkbox click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclick, onclicklistener

I cannot detect when and which checkbox gets clicked from script below:

HTML Snippet:

```
<label for="checkbox[1]"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" id="checkbox[1]" class="detectThisChange" value="10.00" checked=""> Amount $10.00</label>
<label for="checkbox[2]"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" id="checkbox[2]" class="detectThisChange" value="20.00" checked=""> Amount $20.00</label>
<label for="checkbox[3]"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" id="checkbox[3]" class="detectThisChange" value="30.00" checked=""> Amount $30.00</label>
```

jQuery Snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
// ... //
        $('.detectThisChange').change(function(event){
          var targetID = triggerEvent.target.id; // get the id that triggered the event
          var posStart = targetID.indexOf('[') + 1;
          var posEnd = targetID.indexOf(']');
          var i = targetID.substring(posStart, posEnd); // get the index of the id that triggered the event

          if ( $('#checkbox\\['+ i +'\\]').prop('checked') != true ) {
            alert('checkbox ' + i + ' was checked');
          }
          else {
            alert('checkbox ' + i + ' was unchecked');
          }

        });
// ... //
  }); // end .load()
}); // end .ready()
```

**Appended:**

The problem I am experiencing is that none of my alerts work. So that tells me the change() function is not firing.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919716/detect-checkbox-state-change

Comment: Replace `!=` with `==`

Comment: Ok, thanks @97ldave. In the selected answer, what does the id `frameName` part of `jQuery("#frameName").contents()` represent?

Comment: Thank you @BhojendraSah. See my appended comment in my OQ. The change() function is not even firing.

Comment: Thanks @Invent-Animate. My problem is I cannot get to my change() function.

Comment: @H.Ferrence Is your code inside ready???

Comment: yes it is @Bhojendra Sah

Comment: assure you have class detectThisChange

Comment: You don't need to use load()...

Comment: ok, @BhojendraSah. This is a mature script that I had in place for over a year. I am adding new functionality. I don't want other parts to break. So are you saying that this new `.change(function()` is not working because of `load()` ?

Comment: Are you maybe adding this html dinamically?

Comment: yes I am @EvertonLenger. Does that make a difference?

Comment: See my answer below.. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are adding this HTML dinamically, you should use the .on() method, like:

```
$(document).on('change', '.detectThisChange', function() {
    // your code
});
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I've fallen into this so many times that it's the first thing I check when it doesn't work.. Glad that helped! :)

Comment: This the **only** way that I could get the `.on('change', ...` to fire. Works with `.on('click',...)` also. Others did not. BTW, I was also struck for hours trying to get it to fire using the same method which of course was failing.

Answer (score 7):

Try like this

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked") // returns boolean checked or unchecked
```

---

```
   var arr = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.is(':checked')) {
            arr.push(self.attr("id"));
        }
    });
    console.log(arr);
```

**EdIted:**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.is(":checked")) {
        console.log("checkbox  id =" + self.attr("id") + "is checked ");
    } else {
        console.log("Id = " + self.attr("id") + "is Unchecked ");
    }
});
```

**Edited 2 :**

```
$("body").on('change','.detectThisChange', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.is(":checked")) {
        console.log("checkbox  id =" + self.attr("id") + "is checked ");
    } else {
        console.log("Id = " + self.attr("id") + "is Unchecked ");
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yo81j2cw/2/)**

Comment: I need to get my event listener to work first @Satindersingh. Then I am sure your answer will work.

Comment: that looks like a new approach. give me a moment to try it @Satindersingh

Comment: But I have over 20+ check boxes ion my script @Satindersingh. Is this going to fire on every checkbox when checked?

Comment: @H.Ferrence : you can set your selector accordingly like if you want for element having class `detectThisChange`  then use `$(".detectThisChange").on('change',function(){});`

Comment: I did that from the beginning @Satindersingh. That is what caused me to come here to post

Comment: @H.Ferrence: have updated my answer again, pls check and let me know whatever error occurs in console

Answer (score 2):

Try on `change` event with this id selector as `'input[id^=checkbox]'`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[id^=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value, this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');//fire event on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="checkbox[1]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" id="checkbox[1]" class="detectThisChange" value="10.00" checked="">Amount $10.00</label>
<label for="checkbox[2]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" id="checkbox[2]" class="detectThisChange" value="20.00" checked="">Amount $20.00</label>
<label for="checkbox[3]">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" id="checkbox[3]" class="detectThisChange" value="30.00" checked="">Amount $30.00</label>
```

Comment: thanks @Arvind. It did not work for me even though I know it works for you. I just can't get my change to fire.

Comment: @H.Ferrence, any errors on the console? which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(".detectThisChange").on('change', function () {

    alert("In the function");
    var targetID = this.id; // get the id that triggered the event
    var posStart = targetID.indexOf('[') + 1;
    var posEnd = targetID.indexOf(']');
    var i = targetID.substring(posStart, posEnd); // get the index of the id that triggered the event

    if ($('#checkbox\\[' + i + '\\]').prop('checked') == true) {
        alert('checkbox ' + i + ' was checked');
    } else {
        alert('checkbox ' + i + ' was unchecked');
    }
});
```

Here's the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/DTcHh/2915/)**, even though you have an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:)

```
if ( $('#checkbox\\['+ i +'\\]').is(":checked") ) {
  alert('checkbox ' + i + ' was checked');
}
else {
  alert('checkbox ' + i + ' was unchecked');
}
```

Comment: I am sure your answer will work @BhojendraSah once I get the change()function to fire.