# JQuery - Hide Table Columns

Tags: jquery

I am currently learning about JQuery. I've saved the JQuery file in my wwwroot folder. The script and HTML is as follows:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.2.0.js">
</head>
<script>
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
</script>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="first_name" checked="checked"> First Name 
  <input type="checkbox" name="last_name"> Last Name 
  <input type="checkbox" name="email" checked="checked"> Email</p>

<table id="report">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th class="first_name">First Name</th>
 <th class="last_name">Last Name</th>
 <th class="email">Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td class="first_name">Larry</td>
 <td class="last_name">Hughes</td>
 <td class="email">larry@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="first_name">Mike</td>
 <td class="last_name">Tyson</td>
 <td class="email">mike@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to add and remove columns via the checkbox, but its simply not working. 
I cannot understand why it wouldn't work? Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: After your page has loaded in the browser, open the browser console and enter `$`.  Does it show '$ is not defined'?  If so, you're not getting jquery, if not, it's something else (but first things first).

Comment: This selector: `input:checkbox:not(:checked)` will only bind to the checkboxes that are unticked at time of load.  (that might be intended, but it's a little unusual)

Comment: @freedomn-m it says 'function jquery()'

Comment: @freedomn-m any other suggestions?

Comment: When you call your code, it acts on any elements that exist at that time.  As your code is *before* the elements, there aren't any, so does nothing.  You have two choices, best: wrap in `$(document).ready(function() { ..code here.. });` (which has already been suggested as an answer) - 2nd: put your code at the end, just before `</html>` rather than at the top.  It's a short-term fix though and document.ready is the way to go.

Comment: In your script block, add: `alert($("input:checkbox").length)` - it will be zero.  Now put the same alert at the end and, assuming jquery is working, it will show a correct count.

Comment: This is clearly a homework question, second one I've seen today

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do the following :

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
        $(column).toggle();
    }else{
      var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
        $(column).hide();   
    }
});
```

Do detect a modification on a checkbox.
Ref : [How to detect a checkbox click in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636704/how-to-detect-a-checkbox-click-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code in document.ready function

```
  $(document).ready(function () {     
       $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
            var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
            $(column).hide();
        });

        $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
            var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
            $(column).toggle();
        });
   });
```

Comment: "need init if jquery is called"

Comment: Do you have any other code in your page than that supplied in the question?